# make image appear within another div on css hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like an image to appear within a div upon the state of another element changing, so when .main-menu: hover is called, I'd like an image to appear in #logo

```
<body><div class="area">

    </div><nav class="main-menu"><div id="logo"></div><div id="logo_text"></div>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            UI Components
                        </span>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
                   </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
  </body>



.main-menu {
background:#3D3D3D;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;

}

#logo {

  position: relative;
  text-align: center;

}


  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("logo").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("logo_text").style.display = "block";
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("logo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("logo_text").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

I know the java script works I'm just not sure where and how to initiate it when the CSS hover is called.

I have also tried using:

```
.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {

    width:250px;
    overflow:visible;
    content: url(image.PNG);
    display: block;

    }
```

which did function but rendered the image at 100% of the main-menu:hover nav when active so if there's a way control the image size using this that may even be prefreable.

Thanks
James

Comment: Where's your html?

Comment: Are you sure this works: `.main-menu:hover{content: url(image.PNG);}`? I tested this and it seems not work.

Comment: it's defiantly working though the image is too large when actives the image appears in .main-menu rather than #logo where it was intended to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pesudo alements `after` or `before` and you can manage them how ever you want:

```
.main-menu:hover::after, nav.main-menu.expanded::after {
    overflow:visible;
    content: url(image.PNG);
    display: block;
    width: 100px;  
    margin-left: .... 
}
```

And if your script is same as you write here, There only second script lock works.

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately as I'm using the content property which doesn't make use of the img tag.

Comment: Does the image appear on hover? I test this but it seems does not work. I think the `content` property, only works in `::after` and `::before`.

Comment: You can't use content for images. You need to define it in your html. or as a background.

Comment: it appears to work on hover when at 100%, however if I try `transform: scale(.5);` the image then only appears in `::after` and `::before`

Comment: @DannyvanHolten it is possible to use image as content. Just now i tested. But it must use after and before pesudo, not element itself.

Comment: I've got it working using your example with `after` or `before`, it's now just in the wrong position but I'm sure I can work that bit out. Thanks for your help

Comment: You welcome my friend ... :)  And if the answer is benefit, You can point it so others may use this post.

Comment: To change its position, you can use styles for this normally. You can assume `after` and `before` as individual elements that could be styled individually.

Comment: You welcome my friend. But as i said in my previous comment, It is better to accept the true answer, so other people may use this post. It is good for both of us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with the structure you have you can do this. do the following to test:

**0: Remove these javascripts code you posted from the page**

**1:** Write something inside the `#logo` tag.

**2:** Add `visibility: hidden;` to the `#logo` CSS properties.

**3:** Add this to the end of the CSS file/block (of your example):

> .main-menu:hover #logo{   visibility: visible; }

So, with this, when you hover the `.main-menu`, the `#logo` will be visible.
If you need `#logo` to be visible at start, so put the image that will start visible inside the `#logo` tag, and also put the hidden imagem inside the `#logo` tag with a specific class, and use:

> .main-menu:hover #logo .yourClass{   visibility: visible; }

to show that new image.

Note that this only works because in the DOM tree the `#logo` tag is inside `.main-menu` tag.
If they are in diferente trees, then this is not possible with CSS only, and javascript will be required to change some classes.